# Focus on inputs with the same class, but affect just one at a time

Tags: select, input, mootools

I want to make an action when I click(focus)/clickout(blur) on inputs that have the same class, but just the input I clicked should be affected not all of them as in my example here http://jsfiddle.net/HTZr2/
**click on a input, now all the descriptions are showing. I'd like to show just the description of the input I click.

```
<div class="form-wrapper">
    <div class="form-element ">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" autofocus="autofocus" tabindex="1">
        <p class="description">First's input description!</p>
    </div>
</div> 
<div class="form-wrapper">
    <div class="form-element ">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" autofocus="autofocus" tabindex="1">
        <p class="description">Second's input description!</p>
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="form-wrapper">
    <div class="form-element ">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" autofocus="autofocus" tabindex="1">
        <p class="description">Third's input description!</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-wrapper">
    <div class="form-element ">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" autofocus="autofocus" tabindex="1">
        <p class="description">Forth's input description!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my JS:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
  $$('.form-element > input').addEvents({
  focus: function(){ 
      $$('.form-element').addClass('form_element_active')
      },
  blur: function(){
      $$('.form-element').removeClass('form_element_active');
      }    
  }); 
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so just get the parent el:

```
$$('.form-element > input').addEvents({
    focus: function () {
        this.getParent('.form-element').addClass('form_element_active')
    },
    blur: function () {
        this.getParent('.form-element').removeClass('form_element_active');
    }
});
```